# How do I Fix this Mesh? (Bad Shading)

Tags: mesh, vertices

I'm working on a hand and I tried connecting the thumb using Merge at Center [M], but I came across this mesh error and I'm unsure how to resolve this. I used Merge by distance but it's not working, I redid the whole hand however the same issue reoccured. How can this be solved.

[image: Front view]

[image: Back view]

Comment: We need informations on your geometry, please add close-up screenshots of the concerned geometry or upload your blend file https://blend-exchange.com/. Could be because of double vertices, bad normals, ...

Comment: It looks like you have flipped normals, try to select all in Edit mode and press Shift N

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, recalculating modules worked.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 5):

As we can see if we display the face orientation you have flipped faces, you need to select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate.

[image]