# Weird Creases after I subdivision

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, mirror

[image: Before using Subdivsion Modifier]
[image: After using Subdivision Modifier]

Hi guys, I am new to blender and now working on my character. weird creases appear on my character after using the Subdivision modifier. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Hello it may be inverted normals, check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314390/how-do-i-fix-this-mesh/314391#314391 or inner faces?